# How do I watch 3d video on Sony Vaio FW46M with Epson EH-TW6000

Tags: sony-vaio, 3d

I've got:

1. Epson EH-TW6000W
2. Sony Vaio VGN-FW46M Laptop with HDMI output
3. WinDvd 11 Pro (3D)
4. Windows 8 RC

How do I watch YouTube 3d channel on this http://www.youtube.com/3d?

Can I use this sony laptop to wacth 3d at all (something about hdmi 1.4)?

Comment: What happens when you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it all out at least with youtube.

1. First open a 3d video on youtube and set the 3d mode to side by side
2. Connect the projector to the pc (hdmi or any other connection, it does not seem to matter)
3. Go to projector setting Signal -> 3d settings -> 3d input type (change auto to side-by-side)
4. Start the video in full screen (on your pc you should be able two see to pictures, but the project will show only one, no 3d yet)
5. Switch projector in 3d mode (by pushing 2d/3d button) - now the picture should get blurry
6. Switch you 3d glasses on -> now it should be 3d 3d!

Simple, ah.